# Multiple divs and multiple dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using css wildcards selectors and jquery wildcard selectors in my project. Everything seems to work fine if I only have one result but if I have two dialogs then I got strange results.

Working with selectors and only one dialog and div:

[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ntenisOT/Jrkpe/21/)

Working with selectors and two dialogs and divs:

[Not working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ntenisOT/Jrkpe/24/)

1. In order to see the error just move the two dialogs side by side. First click inside the first dialog and the form fields will get the correct value. Afterwards click inside the second dialog. The values are wrong. I think is calculating the values according the div inside the 1st dialog.
2. Secondly, in Firefox I have some strange results after clicking inside the 1st dialog. For example I get x = 12.[2139219329193] some random numbers instead of just an integer.

**Desirable result:**

When you click inside a dialog I want to get the correct coordinates according the div inside the dialog. I want co-ordinates between 0,0 and 320,400 which is the size of the two images!

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the expected outcome is.

Comment: When you click inside a dialog I want to get the correct coordinates according the div inside the dialog. I want co-ordinates between 0,0 and 320,400 which is the size of the two images!

Comment: why are you calling `.dialog('open')` over and over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
var o = $("[id^=pointer_div]").dialog("open").offset();
```

With this:

```
var o = $(this).dialog("open").offset();
```

---

The former will find both pointer DIV's again, call `dialog("open")` on both, and then return `offset()` for the **first** of the elements found.

Whereas the second version uses `this`, which, when used inside a `click` handler, will always point to the specific element that was clicked.

Comment: Thanks mate its working. I was using `this.dialog("open").offset();` and it was not working. Can you please explain me the difference between `this.` and `$(this).`. Finally do you know how to fix the strange issue with the numbers in Firefox?

Comment: The difference is that in this case, `this` is a [plain DOM Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node). If you pass it to `$()` it's wrapped in a jQuery object, which allows you to call `dialog` and `offset` (and loads of other stuff) on it.

Comment: At to the Firefox "issue", have you tried [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)?